# RewriteRule dropping escaped parameter

Tags: rewrite, rewritecond

I need some help with the following RewriteRule:

RewriteRule ^/iesearch/(.*)$ /jsp/search/ieaccelerators/visualsearch.jsp?q=$1 [L,PT]

The intention is to rewrite search-queries from `http://mydomain/iesearch/alvin+the+chip` to a JSP. This works fine as long as the URL does not contain encoded characters such as: `http://mydomain/iesearch/alvin+%26+the+chip`.

The rewrite log shows the following: 
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /iesearch/alvin+&+the+chip

(2) rewrite '/iesearch/alvin+the+&+chip' -> '/jsp/search/ieaccelerators/visualsearch.jsp?q=alvin+&+the+chip'

(3) split uri=/jsp/search/ieaccelerators/visualsearch.jsp?q=alvin+&+the+chip -> uri=/jsp/search/ieaccelerators/visualsearch.jsp, args=q=alvin+&+the+chip

I would have hoped that the %26 is passed on instead of the &.

Answer (score 0):

The `[B]` flag should force the query string to be escaped, i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^/iesearch/(.*)$ /jsp/search/ieaccelerators/visualsearch.jsp?q=$1 [L,PT,B]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this sorted like so:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /iesearch/([^\ ]*)\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^/iesearch/ /jsp/search/ieaccelerators/visualsearch.jsp?q=%1 [NE,PT,L]